# Cypress - How to get element using value in the text field

Tags: automation, cypress

I have couple of text_area_field in my application which can be distinguished only by using the value inside it. How can I get a specific element using value?

Ex:

```
<div data-component="options">
    <input data-component="text_area">Value 1</input>  
    <input data-component="text_area">Value 2</input>  
    <input data-component="text_area">Value 3</input>  
    <input data-component="text_area">Value 4</input>
```

I have tried
`cy.get('[data-component="options"] [data-component="text_area"]').contains('Value 3').clear().type('Edited 3')`.
but it is giving the error :
Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'Value 3' within the element:  but never did

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: updated. It is kept jsu as a reference

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `div` allows typing. If yes, try the below code and see if that is working:

```
cy.get('[data-component="options"] [data-component="text_area"]').each(($div, i) => {
            const valueText = Cypress.$($div).text();
            console.log(valueText);
            if(valueText === "Value 3") {
              cy.wrap($div).clear().type("Edited 3");
            }
        })
```

You could also try using `eq()`, but if there are changes in selector with more options it may fail.

```
cy.get('[data-component="options"] > div').eq(2).then(($div)=>{
     cy.wrap($div).contains("Value 3").clear().type("Edited 3");
 })
```

You could possibly try this one too:

```
cy.get('[data-component="options"] > div').contains("Value 3").clear().type("Edited 3");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work .Try this code:

```
cy.get('[data-component="options"] > div').invoke('show').eq(2).then(($div)=>{
 cy.wrap($div).contains("Value 3").clear().type("Edited 3");
 })
```